# python random number

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone can clarify this line for me.

> Create a function die(x) which rolls a
>   die x times keeping track of how many
>   times each face comes up and returns a
>   1X6 array containing these numbers.

I am not sure what this means when it says 1X6 array ? I am using the randint function from numpy so the output is already an array (or list) im not sure.

Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def die(x):
    return np.bincount(np.random.random_integers(0, 5, size=x))
```

`np.random.random_integers(0,5,size=x)` rolls the die `x` times (faces are represented by numbers from `0` to `5` including).

`np.bincount()` returns the number of occurrences of each value in the array i.e., how many times each face comes up.

#### Example

```
>>> a = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, size=10)
>>> a
array([3, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 1, 3, 0])
>>> np.bincount(a)
array([3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4])
```

Answer (score 3):

Since a dice has 6 possible outcomes, if you get a 2 three times, this would be :

0 3 0 0 0 0

Comment: Thanks. So if my output is [1,5,5,2,3,4,6] (a list) how can I count the total lets say "2" values?

Comment: the array that you specify in your example is 1x7. But if it was [1,5,5,2,3,4], the "2" values would be 5.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the array 0 index with a zero position. In programming terms, array[0] actually represents the "1"s, array[1] represents the "2"s and so on..

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
def die(x):
    return [np.random.randint(1,6) for i in range(x)]
```

Comment: Hi, This is what I currently have but my question is not to find the answer but to understand what exactly its asking for. Using what you did before is what I did, I have a list of all the random values but im not sure what to do from there. Is my function returning the list of all the x outcomes or a total count for all the 1s, 2s, 3s in an array.. If the second one... how can I count the individual values from the list?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the results of the die rolls in a list `lst`, you can determine the number of times a 4 appeared by doing `len([_ for _ in lst if _ == 4])`.  you should be able to figure the rest out from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> myarray = [0]*6
>>> roll = 2
>>> myarray[roll-1]+=1
>>> myarray
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> myarray[roll-1]+=1
>>> myarray
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> roll = 6
>>> myarray[roll-1]+=1
>>> myarray
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

now you just need to set roll from `randint()` or similar